# Microsoft Dynamics Integration with Magnolia

Tags: magnolia

We need Magnolia 5.5 integration with Microsoft Dynamics(CRM) but as per the following magnolia documentation the integration is not available out of the box with Magnolia. [Magnolia Documentation](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Integration#Integration-MarketingandCRM.)

How can we build that functionality in Magnolia, please advice.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

All depends on what kind of API Dynamics exposes for such integration. And what features of Dynamics exactly do you want to integrate.

If there is any REST based API, you can have a look at similar integrations (those for SugarCRM, Eloqua or SalesForce come to my mind) and do what needs to be done. Source code for the above integrations provided by Magnolia is AFAIK available to all Enterprise customers.

Typically you have two parts of the integrations
- backend one where you create content connector for an app and the app directly to allow your editors to interact and select items from Dynamics, and
- some templating functions that allow templates to understand items previously selected by the editors and retrieve those from Dynamics when rendering the template.
- typically you will also have to deal somehow with authentication between Magnolia and Dynamics and (unless all is super fast) with caching items retrieved from Dynamics in Magnolia in some form of volatile cache.

But really, any more details on what to do and how depends on the use case. It would be different for building customer self service portal and for e.g. just listing phone number of the sales/support rep closest to visitor of the site based on geolocation.